# Goldbach for almost primes

Tags: analytic-number-theory

I have finished some courses on analytic number theory and wanted to learn about versions of Goldbach so I can pick a topic for my master thesis.

I have seen a proof for an asymptotic formula for the tenary Goldbach conjecture in the lecture. I can not find the paper where the version of Goldbach for a prime and an almost prime was proven.I hope someone here can help.

Comment: FYI, the [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldbach%27s_conjecture#Rigorous_results) says "In 1948, using sieve theory, [Alfréd Rényi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alfr%C3%A9d_R%C3%A9nyi) showed that every sufficiently large even number can be written as the sum of a prime and an almost prime with at most K factors.[(24)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldbach%27s_conjecture#cite_note-Alfr%C3%A9d_R%C3%A9nyi_1948-24)".

Comment: Chen's theorem (any even number large enough is a sum of a prime and a number which is either a prime or a product of two primes) is presented in Nathanson Classical Basis and there are more references there

Comment: By the way, it's been proven that the number of exceptions to Goldbach up to $x$ is at most $x^{1-\delta}$ for some $\delta > 0$. That is, we have pretty good upper bounds on the number of violations to Goldbach (if there are any).

Comment: I dont really know how to find a proof.For example it is proved in this paper https://londmathsoc.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1112/plms/s2-44.4.307, but I dont have any access to it.

Comment: Are you talking about Chen's theorem?

Comment: I think your professor must have referred to Helfgott: https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~harald.helfgott/anglais/book.html - If that answers your question, let me know.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I got sick. I was talking about the proof that goldbach is true for almost all integers. I also want to award al-Hwarizmi somehow. Thanks a lot.